# Updating field in SQL, if match one of many value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update a column, if another column matches one of very many values. Currently I'm doing it like this, but there must be a better way of doing it?

```
UPDATE table
SET Column1 ='awesomeness'
WHERE Column2 LIKE 'somedata' 
    OR Column2 LIKE 'someotherdata' 
    OR Column2 LIKE 'someotherdataagain' 
    OR Column2 LIKE 'orthis' 
    OR Column2 LIKE 'orthat';
```

I'm thinking something like this should be possible:

```
UPDATE table
SET Column1 ='awesomeness'
WHERE Column2 LIKE ('somedata' OR 'someotherdata' OR 'someotherdataagain' OR 'andthis' OR 'andthat');
```

But that doesn't work, and moving the first parenthasis in front of "Column2" just run the update on every single row in the table.

EDIT: I'm sorry my first post wasn't accurate. I am actually using wildcards, so my query looks something like this

```
UPDATE table
SET Column1 ='awesomeness'
WHERE Column2 LIKE 'somedata____' 
    OR Column2 LIKE 'someotherdata____' 
    OR Column2 LIKE 'orthis____' 
    OR Column2 LIKE 'orthat____';
```

Comment: `LIKE` is not for all string comparisons. Only use `LIKE` if you need its pattern-matching capabilities (wild card, case, etc). When you want an exact string, use `=` or `IN`. Even if you only need to match case, it's often more convenient to set the case to upper for both compared items.

Comment: @MPelletier is correct.  Are you trying to match with wildcards?  If not, dont use like.  Use the `IN` suggestion of Donal

Comment: Based on your edit, that's the only way I can think of to do it.  Is there something wrong with what you've got so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IN` clause. It will look like this:

```
UPDATE table SET 
Column1 ='awesomeness' 
WHERE 
Column2 IN ('somedata', 'someotherdata' ,'someotherdataagain', 'andthis', 'andthat');
```

As others have stated, the `IN` clause will not work for a wildcard `LIKE` query - if you are using wildcards.

If you want to perform a case-insensitive `IN` - you can convert Column2 to lowercase using the `LOWER` function. In this scenario and because all your strings are in lower case - the case in Column2 would be ignored. For example:

```
UPDATE table SET 
Column1 ='awesomeness' 
WHERE 
LOWER(Column2) IN ('somedata', 'someotherdata' ,'someotherdataagain', 'andthis', 'andthat');
```

If you want use wild cards, you can use the SQL wildcard symbol `%`, for example:

```
UPDATE table
SET Column1 ='awesomeness'
WHERE LOWER(Column2) LIKE 'somedata%' OR LOWER(Column2) LIKE 'someotherdata%' OR LOWER(Column2) LIKE 'orthis%' OR LOWER(Column2) LIKE 'orthat%';
```

Comment: I suspect the OP meant `=` and not `like`. But if the OP did mean  `like`, it won’t work.

Comment: @EtienneMiret ok, understood. But the OP is not using any wildcards - so I am not sure. All the values the OP is comparing is lower case - so I guess we could use LOWER around Column2?

Comment: I am actually using wildcards, my first post wasn't accurate, see edit

Comment: @Znerox I'm afraid you are SOL then. You will have to use: WHERE Column2 LIKE 'somedata____' OR Column2 LIKE 'someotherdata____' OR Column2 LIKE 'orthis____' OR Column2 LIKE 'orthat____'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do exact matches of Column2 against some strings. In this situation you can change the LIKE operator by the = operator, and because of that, you can use the IN operator for multiple values.

So, your query would look like that:

UPDATE table SET column1 = 'value1' where column2 IN ('value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'valueN');

Answer (score 0):

You can put the wildcard values inside a table variable and join to it.

```
create table Words (Word varchar(100));

insert into Words (Word)
values ('Computer'),('Monitor'),('Mouse'),('Keyboard');


declare @match table (Wildcard varchar(100))

insert into @match (Wildcard)
values ('%put%'),('M%')
-- Computer, Monitor, Mouse should match


update w
set Word = 'New' + Word
from Words w
join @match m
  on w.Word like m.Wildcard

select * from Words
```

You can demo it here... [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce2cfe/4)